# como editar un archivo en Dockerfile

Tags: nodejs, docker

Hola es que tengo este archivo en mi proyecto node, y quiero ingresar al archivo que esta ubicado en src/Config/config.json y quiero desde docker modificar la contraseña de test que pase de null a "contrasenaMySql"

```
{
  "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_production",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
}
```

este es mi dockerFile

```
FROM node:16-slim

USER node

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app

WORKDIR /home/node/app


COPY --chown=node package*.json ./

RUN npm install 

COPY --chown=node . .

ENV HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=3000

EXPOSE ${PORT}

CMD [ "node", "." ]

WORKDIR /home/node/app/src

RUN npm install --save-dev sequelize-cli

RUN npx sequelize-cli init

RUN npx sequelize-cli db:seed:all
```

Comment: no lo enfocaria asi el problema. Te diria que mejor utilices, aparte del dockerfile para crear la imagen y demas, añadas un docker-compose. Con este ultimo puedes hacer un montaje del archivo local sobre el que hay en el docker, y asi puedes modificarlo las veces que quieras...

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría el siguiente enfoque en el Dockerfile

```
RUN sed -i "s|alguna-cadena-original|la-nueva-cadena |g" /src/Config/config.json
```

Este comando buscará  **alguna-cadena-original** en el archivo config.json remplazará con **la-nueva-cadena**

Comment: @padaleiana Muchas gracias por tu comentario